# Symmetric coefficients imply symmetric solutions?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

Let us consider any one-diomensional ODE of the form: $$
\dfrac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}}+a(x)y(x)+b(x)=0,
$$
where $a,b:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ are both even functions. Does these hypothesis implies that the solution $y(x)$ must to be even, regardless what $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ actually? Are there some non-symmetric solution for some specific even functions $a(x)$ and $b(x)$? Same question if I change the hypothesis on $b(x)$ for odd function. Does that implies that the solution must to be odd? Edit: I just realize that $y(x)$ could be odd, even if $a(x)$ is even just by assuming $b(x)\equiv0$. But, what about if I add the hypothesis of $y(x)>0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No : constant functions are even. But the solutions of $y'' = y$ are not all even (for example, $\sinh (x)$ is not)

Edit : with the same equation, $e^x$ is a positive solution which is not even or odd.

The fact is, if $y$ is even, then $y'$ is odd. So, if you want an even solution, your initial conditions must have $y'(0) = 0$. If you impose a nonzero value at $0$ for the derivative, you have a non even solution.

Comment: Sorry, I think you didn't see my edit. That run out this case.

Comment: Say $a=-1$ and $b=0$, then $e^{x} + 2e^{-x}$ is a positive solution but is not even.